# How to use numpy to sort out the object positions in rows in the image?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a image with many blue circles drawn randomly. I can use simple opencv to detect the coordinates of these values and extract a array of coordinates values [x1, x2, y1, y2], which represents the the top-left and bottom-right coordinates of the object in the image,

Now I need to sort out the array, according to the order from left to right and from bottom to top.the order can be seen from the figure below (the text near the blue circle is considered as the index of the array).

I can use for loop to do the job , but that is too complicated, I wonder how would I sort the array in numpy so that the array can be indexed as the image shown below.

[image]

Comment: Show your loopy code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.lexsort` to do a stable sort by two keys. For the ordering in your image, use a y value as the primary sort key (last argument in `lexsort`) and an x value as the secondary sort key (first argument in `lexsort`).

```
import numpy as np

# array of [x1, x2, y1, y2] positions
dat = np.array([[3,4,1,2],
                [3,4,0,1],
                [1,2,1,2],
                [0,1,1,2],
                [1,2,0,1],
                [0,1,0,1]])

# stably sort by x1 then y1
sorted_dat = dat[np.lexsort((dat[:, 0], dat[:, 2]))]

print(sorted_dat)
#  [[0 1 0 1]
#   [1 2 0 1]
#   [3 4 0 1]
#   [0 1 1 2]
#   [1 2 1 2]
#   [3 4 1 2]]
```